Flutter Web navigation
I am developing an app using Flutter for the web. I was able to change the URL according to the tapped bottom navigation item. For example, if I have Home, Profile, and Settings in the navigation bar, the URL switches to /home, /profile, and /settings accordingly. However, the problem I am facing right now is the reverse: if I directly enter the URL (e.g., http://localhost:8080/profile), it navigates to the profile screen, but the highlighted tab remains the first index, which is Home.
In my router, I use GoRoute and StatefulShellBranch. Has anyone encountered this issue before and managed to solve it? If so, could you please share your solutions with me? Thank you!

Please paste your code here.
